# How to click an element, using Selenium and a predefined text?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to click the below element using text:

```
<div class="card card card-search-result">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 search-model">Grande Punto 199
        <span>(2007 to 2009)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The suggested command is the following:

```
m = "Punto 199 (2007 to 2009)"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[contains(text(), '{m}')]"))).click()
```

The problem is that the text cannot be recognized in this element except if i modify m in order to be like:

```
m = "Punto 199"
```

In that case, my code doesn't work because there are instances of elements which include similar information like:

```
<div class="card card card-search-result">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 search-model">Grande Punto 199
        <span>(2008 to 2010)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, span information is important an should be considered during clicking. Any ideas on how to click these elements using all the text information?

I tried also that

```
model_button_xpath = f"//*[contains(text(), '{m}')]/parent::div"
model_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, model_button_xpath)))
model_element.click()
```

Any idea?